# Allow unauthenticated parameter does not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, yaml, cicd

I am creating a CICD pipeline, via GitHub and Google Cloud Build, using the following .yaml file:

```
# Cloud Function specifications
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - hello_world
  - --source=./src
  - --trigger-http
  - --memory=1024MB
  - --max-instances=5
  - --runtime=python39
  - --region=europe-west6
  - --entry-point=predict
  - --allow-unauthenticated
```

Everything works fine and the function deploys correctly; however, whenever I try to call it, the following error is thrown:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
```

It seems like the --allow-unauthenticated parameter isn't working properly.
How can I expose the API and give public access?

[image: Predict function allows unauthenticated, hello_world doesn't]

Note:

if I run `gcloud functions describe --project=XXXXXX --region=europe-west6 hello_world`

I get:

```
availableMemoryMb: 1024
buildId: 1234
entryPoint: predict
environmentVariables:
  ABC: '"discount"'
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_OPTIONAL
  url: https://europe-west6-XXX.cloudfunctions.net/hello_world
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
maxInstances: 5
name: projects/XXX/locations/europe-west6/functions/hello_world
runtime: python39
serviceAccountEmail: XXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-europe-west6XXX
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2021-06-10T17:09:55.950Z'
versionId: '2'
```

Comment: what happens when you run: "gcloud functions describe --project=XXXXXX --region=europe-west6 hello_world"? where XXXXXX is the target project id

Comment: Please, check the edit @al-dann

Comment: I can only speculate based on documnetation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation => "Subsequent deployments of the same function do not change its status..." however it is not obvious if it is applicable to your case.  Personally I would try https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment to see if that can help

Comment: Use of the --allow-unauthenticated flag modifies IAM permissions. To ensure that unauthorized developers cannot modify function permissions, the user or service that is deploying the function must have the cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy permission. This permission is included in both the Owner and Cloud Functions Admin roles.

Thus, as soon as Function Admin role is granted to the Cloud Build Service Account, everythin works; if you answer I'll happily accept that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use of the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag modifies IAM permissions.

To ensure that unauthorized developers cannot modify function permissions, the user or service that is deploying the function must have the
`cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy` permission (as noted [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation)).

This aforementioned permission is included in both Owner and Cloud Functions Admin roles. Thus, as soon as the Function Admin role is granted to the Cloud Build Service Account, everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the command to allow unauthenticated access (allow-unauthenticated) failed because you did not have the correct IAM roles to change that setting? This is an interesting point for deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify cloud build service account permissions and add function admin role, it should work.